# как изменить размеры Bitmap?

Tags: java, android, изображения, bitmap, камера

Я делаю снимок и предварительно сохраняю его в 'ArrayList Bitmap' и перед тем как сохранить снимки на карту я вывожу их в 'GridView'. Но из-за того, что картинка 'Bitmap' большого размера то в  'GridView' они отображаются не корректно. Я пробовал перед сохранением сделать так

```
bitmap.setHeight();
bitmap.setWidth();
```

Но студия подчеркивает и говорит, что я не могу использовать эти методы. Если я правильно понял то это связано с API.

Посоветуйте как сделать картинку 50 на 50 пикселей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так понимаю, вы ищете способ масштабирования Bitmap`а до нужных размеров.
В таком случае следует использовать метод масштабирования до нужных размеров:

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmal, newWidth, newHeight, isFilter)
```

Подробнее можно почитать на [developers.android](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)), как обычно.

Comment: и когда уже developers.android научится делать нормальную справку по своим функциям, для людей. Вот как же удобно у Microsoft: справочка с примерами и связанными функциями - скопировал и забыл как называется. У java же надо чтобы человек помучился, прострадал:)